# Django_nose doesn't load basic fixtures, e.g. django_site example.com entry or admin permissions

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-nose

With the current stable django_nose (0.1.3) the models aren't even properly found and loaded, I get the following exception when running the tests:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'test_appdatabase.django_site' doesn't exist")
```

using the git version of django_nose I managed to get my models to be created into the test database properly, however they are all empty, with Django's testrunner I get some basic data loaded into the tables, such as the django_site and auth_permission tables:

```
django_site
id      domain  name
1       example.com     example.com
```

When I run the test suite with django_nose installed and setup, I get the following exception:

```
DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
```

Any Ideas?

---

Update: running with -v 2, it seems it is running the post-sync handlers (syncdb) for the applications

```
Running post-sync handlers for application sites
Creating example.com Site object
Adding content type 'sites | site'
Adding permission 'sites | site | Can add site'
Adding permission 'sites | site | Can change site'
Adding permission 'sites | site | Can delete site'
```

So it seems to be adding them, yet somewhere they are being deleted.

---

Further Update:

Looking at the MySQL Query log, the sequence of events is

1. Do a syncdb on the test database
2. Truncate every single table (why?, this is where my issue is)
3. Run the tests

An example truncation from the query log:

```
TRUNCATE `django_site`
```

Why are the tables being truncated? Is it so that the tests don't pollute each other, is there a way to disable that?

---

I believe this to be the final update:

using the standard django runner, the same thing happens,

1. tables are created
2. post-sync inserts data
3. the tables are truncated
4. Alter table called to set AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Except for the next step:

1. Data is inserted back in

   INSERT INTO `django_site` (`domain`, `name`) VALUES ('example.com', 'example.com')

Not sure why this is happening here but not with django_nose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diff displayed in https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose/issues/39 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is the `sites` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? The nose test runner extends django's test runner, which should be calling `syncdb` and picking up all your installed apps.
2. What does your test case look like? `django-nose` is not responsible for loading your fixtures (neither is the normal Django test runner). Fixtures get loaded by `django.test.TestCase`.

Edit:
All the things you're describing happen in `_fixture_setup()` from Django's TestCase. The truncate and such happens in `flush` and then the fixtures get set up.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L258

Comment: Yeah you are right, but it is not the fixtures, as you mentioned the syncdb is being called, but then the tables are being truncated, see my latest update above.

Comment: Is the flush command handled differently by django_nose? seems that the django flush emits the post sync signal

Comment: Diff displayed in https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose/issues/39 fixes my issue